# PHP redis connection remain open and connection close not working?

Tags: php, redis

i am trying to close the connection with Redis but its seems not working , the number of open connections is increasing with every refresh !

here is my code :

```
$this->type = $this->api->settings['cache']['type'];
    
if ( $this->type == "Redis" )
{
    
    $this->redis = new Redis(); 
    
    $this->redis->connect( $this->api->settings['cache']['server'] , $this->api->settings['cache']['port'] , 0); 
    
    $this->api->logs->log( array("CACHE" => $this->type, "Connected" => true , "ping" => $this->redis->ping()) );
    
    $this->redis->close();
    $this->redis = null;
}
```

and here is how i monitor live static redis using MAMP pro version , the number of live connections is increasing when i refresh the page , its seems the connections are not closing ? did i miss something ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

will , the solution was i had to update redis to the latest version , since this is a bug in current version .